# Vue passing data to child component

Tags: vue.js

I have an issue where I'm trying to pass an object 'through' one component, which is the overall layout, to child components which sit inside it. I've made a simplified example where I basically have a `<ul></ul>` template and an `<li></li>` template.

I seem to be losing the reference for each one by the time they are created. When I create them, I get the error:

```
vue.js:1023 [Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "model.id": 
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined (found in component:
   <demo-list-item>)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I think I just have a fundamental missing from my knowledge of Vue... I'm really, really new to it and am learning from their website – so this could be a really obvious / silly mistake.

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <demo-list></demo-list>
    <script id="demo-list-template" type="text/x-template">
        <ul>
            <demo-list-item v-for="item in items"></demo-list-item>
        </ul>
    </script>
    <script id="demo-list-item-template" type="text/x-template">
            <li data-id="{{model.id}}">{{ model.name }}</li>
    </script>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// define
var DemoList = Vue.extend({
    template: '#demo-list-template',
    data : function(){
        return {
            'items' : [
                {
                    'id' : 1,
                    'name' : 'this'
                },
                {
                    'id' : 2,
                    'name' : 'that'
                },
                {
                    'id' : 3,
                    'name' : 'something'
                },
                {
                    'id' : 4,
                    'name' : 'nothing'
                }
            ]
      }
    }
});

// List Item
var DemoListItem = Vue.extend({
    template : '#demo-list-item-template'
});

// register
Vue.component('demo-list', DemoList);
Vue.component('demo-list-item', DemoListItem);

// create a root instance
var Vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

Demo:
http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/vXYWgz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Component props doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props), you can pass data to child component like this :

```
<child name="value"></child>
```

and

```
<child :name="value"></child>
```

for dynamic props

So, in your template, when you loop over items array, you got item object. Just pass it to your child component

```
<demo-list-item v-for="item in items" :item="item">
```

Also, in your child component, you have to tell that you attempt to get a prop named `item`

```
var DemoListItem = Vue.extend({
    template : '#demo-list-item-template',
    props: ['item']
});
```

You can validate props, set default value, etc (see doc)

Now, in your child template, you have access to `item` property

```
<li data-id="{{item.id}}">{{ item.name }}</li>
```

Comment: This fixed everything and is a great answer, thanks. Its my first time using Vue so stuff like this is really confusing... `"item in items" :item="item"` is a pretty gnarly moment!

Comment: You can change it to `"item in items" :itemtochild="item"` to be more clear.